# HTML5 Banner with google web designer don't show click count on revive server

Tags: ads, google-web-designer

I have created an HTML5 Banner with google web designer tool, the banner is uploaded and showin on my website but when i click on it the revive-adserver don't count any clicks.

I have also added the configuration for an exit on the tap area, so i'm wondering what i'm missing ?

Please look at the screenshots to see what i did :

[image]

[image]

Statictics photo show impressions but no clicks ?

should i add some other functions on the google web designer ?

Comment: anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted this banner and restarted to create a new one from scratch.